# Relative or independent paths in libtool .la file

Tags: compilation, linker, autotools, libtool

My `.la` file has full pathnames in both the `dependency_libs=` section and the `libdir=` section which makes it difficult to copy my libraries to a different machine (same arch but different path structure). What is the solution to this, besides having some script to hack the `.la` file to adjust for the paths on the new machine?

**==Details==**

When I `./configure; make; make install` my `libfoo`, depending on how I use the `--prefix`, `--exec-prefix`, and `DESTDIR=` flags, I'll get an entry in the `libfoo.la` file that reads `libdir=/dir1/lib` and I'll have the actual `.so` files in the same dir as `libfoo.la`. All is well (in terms of linking something with `libfoo` as it is) until I package these up and put them on another machine.

Let's say I have `libbar` on my second machine which depends on `libfoo`. When I use my `-L/dir2/lib` flag to look for `-lfoo`, the `libbar` compilation/linking fails because of the `libfoo.la` file is expecting foo to be installed in `/dir1/lib` (from the first machine) when it's actually in `/dir2/lib`. I then need to replace all of the `dir1`'s with the correct path, both of which can be long and complicated.

The `dependency_libs=` line also comes into play in a similar manner.

How do I avoid this problem?

Comment: Did you try the [staged installation method from the automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html)?

Comment: I did, that's why I mentioned the prefix and DESTDIR flags. All that can do for me is put my output in a certain directory... same problem though, the .la files will have an absolute path in them, so I run into problems when I move them around

Comment: Have you found any solution for the issue? Except for hacking the `.la` files.

Comment: This was years ago, but I do remember never finding a good solution :-\

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question and also still struggling with this here while cross compiling. Somehow it must be possible to supply a sysroot or something similar to libtool when doing make install right? This is so frustrating having to manually edit the .la dependency paths. Or is it a better practice to not use make install DESTDIR on the host machine to install libraries to a sysroot that you can later copy to the target? So many questions. :D

Answer (score 0):

The question contains some misconceptions, especially here:

> When I use my `-L/dir2/lib` flag to look for `-lfoo`, the `libbar`
> compilation/linking fails because of the `libfoo.la` file is expecting
> foo to be installed in `/dir1/lib`

**If linking with `-L/dir2/lib -lfoo` fails, it is not because of anything in `libfoo.la`.**  The `.la` file is used only by `libtool`.  It is not involved in linking performed by other means.  In fact, it can be removed altogether without impacting linking.  If `/dir2/lib/libfoo.so` is a shared library of the appropriate architecture, and there is otherwise no `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a` in the library search path, then the `-L/dir2/lib -lfoo` options *will* cause a standard Unix compiler or linker that is considering shared libraries at all to attempt to include `/dir2/lib/libfoo.so` in the link.

No link error messages are presented in the question, and this long after the fact, I don't expect any to be added.  Without them, it's unclear what the nature of the problem actually was.  Among the more likely of the many possibilities are

- the library was built for the wrong architecture (presumably, x86 *vs* x86_64).  In this case, a version of the library suitable for the second machine needs to be built from source.
- the ownership and permissions of the library, as installed on the second machine, did not permit the OP's builds there to read it.  In this case, the ownership and / or permissions should be fixed.
- the library had dependencies that were not (correctly) satisfied on the second machine. In this case, the dependencies need to be installed, and probably included in the link, as well.
- the library was inherently sensitive to its installation directory.  This is never the case on Linux, but it may be the case on some other kinds of machines.  In this situation, `libtool` can use the `.la` file to put the library in the location specified for it at build time, but it would need to be rebuilt to be usable from a different location.
- it was never a link error at all, but rather a runtime failure involving the library.  This might happen because `/dir2/lib/libfoo.so` is not in the second system's runtime library search path, or because it depends on other libraries that are not.  On an ELF-based system, `libtool` will have inserted `RPATH` entries into the library, but they are likely to not be appropriate for a different installation directory.  They might even actively cause such an issue.  Updating the dynamic linker's configuration appropriately might help in this situation.

> How do I avoid this problem?

It's not the problem you think it is, and without more information, I can offer only **general advice**:

1. When using an Autotools build system, build for the correct installation directory.  Don't assume that the result will be relocatable to a different installation directory (though it might be).  A different *machine*, yes, if sufficiently alike, but not a different location.  But if you want the best chance of being able to relocate the installation, then
2. Consider using a tool such as `chrpath` to remove the RPATH entry from the library, or even [hacking `libtool` at build time](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#_removing_rpath) to prevent it from adding one in the first place.  Especially if you anticipate installing the library other than in its `configure`d location.
3. Be sure to configure the system's dynamic linker to have the installation directory in its search path.
4. Remove the installed `.la` file if you are changing the installation path, and maybe even if you aren't.
5. Ensure that all the library's dependencies are also installed and in the dynamic linker's search path, and that they are actually compatible.

All of that is consistent with RedHat's RPM packaging guidelines, which cater to exactly the case of building software on one machine for installation and use on another.  It is not all absolutely *required*, however, and there are alternative philosophies about some of that stuff, especially RPATH.  When you have more experience, feel free to ignore as much of that and any other advice on the topic as you like.