# libtool .la library file wrong path

Tags: c++, linker, autotools, libtool

I'm having a similar problem to this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545598/relative-or-independent-paths-in-libtool-la-file).  I'm submitting my code to a build-system to use its g++ binary.  However, the build is moved to a temporary path with a randomly generated name (e.g. `/temp-build/1ab3fDg/...`), while g++ itself is not recompiled and the .la not refreshed (not feasible).  Thus, when libtool looks for the libstdc++.so, it looks in the `/temp-build/1ab3fDg/libstdc++.la` file to get the path to it and sees:

```
libdir=/temp-build/J2213bgB/.../
```

which is the directory of whatever random path gcc was originally compiled in.  The actual .so is in the same directory as the .la file (`/temp-build/1ab3fDg`), but libtool is following the incorrect libdir path.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell libtool to ignore the .la file and look for libstdc++ in a directory specified by me.  Alternatively, is there any other possible solution to this problem?  I'm using autoconf/automake to generate the Makefiles.

Comment: One thing I thought of was to use sed to replace the line with the correct path.  This will work if you have the correct permissions.  Unfortunately, I do not, so I ended up writing a Makefile for the short run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over it, just delete `libstdc++.la`. This is unfortunately a very troublesome design of `libtool`, to hardcode the paths you used to install software in, and it can cause problems such as this.

But the value of `.la` files is very limited, and is usually related to dependency tracking for static archives, that have no other way to express them. But for `libstdc++` there are no dependencies anyway, so the `.la` file is absolutely useless even for the static archive.

For reference, I have written quite a bit on the topic:

- [What about those .la files?](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2008/04/what-about-those-la-files)
- [Posts about .la files](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/tag/lafiles)
- [Autotools Mythbuster on Libtool Archives](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/libtool/lafiles.html)

Comment: `s/the value of .la files/the value of libtool/`